# check if input text field contains min val on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pretty simple HTML web form...

I am taking the data and serializing to JSON *(and will eventually send somewhere else. But, for now am using `console.log` for test).*

When the user fills out the form, and *then* clicks `submit`; I would like to simply check the `value` of my input text field, and make sure the user has at-least entered a number *higher* then `0`, but *not* `0`.

```
        <div>
            <label>Age
                <input type="text" name="age">
            </label>
        </div>
```

I would like this validation to run *before*, my serialize function below it fires. Essentially, I want to check or validate this before data is sent. If the user enters `0`, I don't want to send.

Below is my full JavaScript. *(I still cannot get validate function as described above).*

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('form').submit(function (e) {

        function validateForm(){ // would like to check before below fires for serialize

            var form = document.getElementById("form"), inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"), 

            input = null, flag = true;
            for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
                input = inputs[i];
                // if the value is not a valid number or it's less than or equal 0 
                if(isNaN(input.value) || +input.value < 0) { 
                    flag = false;
                    input.focus();
                        console.log("error!");
                    // break;
                 } 
            }
            return(flag);
        }

    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
    console.log(data);

});
```

Comment: You don't ever call `validateForm()`. Also, `+input.value < 0` should use `<= 0`.

Comment: Can you include more of your HTML? This code is depending on there being a form with id "form", which we can't see. There are other issues, but let's start at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple validate number input. Try this.

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
  inputValue = $("input[name='age']").val();
  var num = parseInt(inputValue);
  if(isNaN(num) || num <= 0){
    console.log(inputValue + " Invalid number!");
  } else {
    console.log(inputValue + " Valid number!");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>Age
        <input type="text" name="age">
    </label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"\>
```

Comment: So, this solves about half of it. Thanks! However, form still submits either way; I don't want to allow submit if form deemed invalid...

Comment: Use return false, or preventDefault to ignore submit action when input number is invalid. Another way you can replace button submit by normal button and submit form whenever it was valid.

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish that, I'm (more or less) usually do this:

**HTML**

```
<form action="(action url)" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    //form contents
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm() { // would like to check before below fires for serialize
    //var form = document.getElementById("form"), inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    //If you use jQuery, it more preferred to write like this:
    var form = $('#form'), inputs = form.find('input'), input = null, flag = true;

    for(var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        // if the value is not a valid number or it's less than or equal 0 
        if(isNaN(input.value) || +input.value < 0) {
            flag = false;
            input.focus();
            console.log("error!");
        }
        //do the break
        if (!flag) break;
    }
    if (flag) {
        var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
        console.log(data);
    }
    return flag;
}
```